# two loops intersect transversally at a single crossing point in the torus

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology

If two simple closed curves intersect transversally at exactly one crossing point in a torus, are they necessary meridian and the longitude of the torus or they may be combination of these two generators?

I think they must be the two generators of the torus (meridian and the longitude), otherwise the points of intersection must be more than one, right?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem correctly. Do you mean, if you have two curves on the torus and they intersect in a single point, is it necessarily the case that one is homotopic to a meridian and the other to a parallel (latitude line)? (Meridian is a synonym for line of longitude, by the way.) In this case, the answer is no.

Comment: Yes, you stated my question correctly. So you say they are not necessarily homotopic to the meridian and the parallel.

Comment: You may consider a toroidal helix instead of a parallel.

Answer (score 2):

A geometric explanation would be..If you cut the torus along one curve, you'll end up with an annulus and since twose two loops intersect only once, if you cut along the other loop you'll get a square...so now you can see the picture that this is (upto a homeomorphism) meridian and longitudinal... so they are generator of the torus as well.

But they are not necessarily homotopic to meridian and longitudinal...for example, starting with meridian and longitudian loop, and apply a Dehn twist along the meridian loop...then you'll endup with one meridian and one other curve which is not homotopic to the longitudinal anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an totally explicit construction of an example:

Let $$\pi : \Bbb R^2 \to (\Bbb R / \Bbb Z) \times (\Bbb R / \Bbb Z) \cong \Bbb S^1 \times \Bbb S^1, \qquad (x, y) \mapsto (x + \Bbb Z, y + \Bbb Z) \sim (e^{2 \pi i x}, e^{2 \pi i y}),$$ be the usual covering of the torus. Then, the images of the $x$- and $y$-axes under $\pi$ are a parallel $P$ and a meridian $M$.

Now, the image of the line $x = ny$, $n \neq 0$, intersects $P$ only at the image $O$ of the origin, but it is not homotopic to $M$ (for either parameterization). It *is* homotopic, however, to a loop that starts at $O$, traces around $M$ once, and then traces around $P$ $n$ times in the 'positive' direction (or $-n$ times in the 'negative' direction). For $n = 1$, this gives the construction in Anubhav's excellent answer.